# JavaScript code is not affecting the output

Tags: javascript, html, css

In below codes the HTML and CSS codes are working fine but the JavaScript code is not affecting the output. The js code is for fadeout in text field.

html code :

```
  <ul class="tab-group">
    <li class="tab active"><a href="#signup">Sign Up</a></li>
    <li class="tab"><a href="#login">Log In</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="signup">   
      <h1>Sign Up for Free</h1>

      <form action="/" method="post">

      <div class="top-row">
        <div class="field-wrap">
          <label>
            First Name<span class="req">*</span>
          </label>
          <input type="text" required autocomplete="off" />
        </div>

        <div class="field-wrap">
          <label>
            Last Name<span class="req">*</span>
          </label>
          <input type="text"required autocomplete="off"/>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="field-wrap">
        <label>
          Email Address<span class="req">*</span>
        </label>
        <input type="email"required autocomplete="off"/>
      </div>

      <div class="field-wrap">
        <label>
          Set A Password<span class="req">*</span>
        </label>
        <input type="password"required autocomplete="off"/>
      </div>

      <button type="submit" class="button button-block"/>Get Started</button>

      </form>

    </div>

    <div id="login">   
      <h1>Welcome Back!</h1>

      <form action="/" method="post">

        <div class="field-wrap">
        <label>
          Email Address<span class="req">*</span>
        </label>
        <input type="email"required autocomplete="off"/>
      </div>

      <div class="field-wrap">
        <label>
          Password<span class="req">*</span>
        </label>
        <input type="password"required autocomplete="off"/>
      </div>

      <p class="forgot"><a href="#">Forgot Password?</a></p>

      <button class="button button-block"/>Log In</button>

      </form>

    </div>

  </div><!-- tab-content -->
```

js code

```
    $('.form').find('input, textarea').on('keyup blur focus', function       (e) {

    var $this = $(this),
     label = $this.prev('label');

     if (e.type === 'keyup') {
        if ($this.val() === '') {
      label.removeClass('active highlight');
      } else {
      label.addClass('active highlight');
      }
      } else if (e.type === 'blur') {
    if( $this.val() === '' ) {
        label.removeClass('active highlight'); 
        } else {
        label.removeClass('highlight');   
        }   
       } else if (e.type === 'focus') {

       if( $this.val() === '' ) {
        label.removeClass('highlight'); 
        } 
        else if( $this.val() !== '' ) {
        label.addClass('highlight');
        }
        }

       });

      $('.tab a').on('click', function (e) {

     e.preventDefault();

      $(this).parent().addClass('active');
       $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('active');

      target = $(this).attr('href');

       $('.tab-content > div').not(target).hide();

     $(target).fadeIn(600);

     });
```

css code :

```
    @import "compass/css3";

$body-bg: #c1bdba;
$form-bg: #13232f;
$white: #ffffff;

$main: #1ab188;
$main-light: lighten($main,5%);
$main-dark: darken($main,5%);

$gray-light: #a0b3b0;
$gray: #ddd;

$thin: 300;
$normal: 400;
$bold: 600;
$br: 4px;

*, *:before, *:after {
box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
overflow-y: scroll; 
}

body {
background:$body-bg;
font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
}

a {
text-decoration:none;
color:$main;
transition:.5s ease;
&:hover {
color:$main-dark;
}
}

.form {
background:rgba($form-bg,.9);
padding: 40px;
max-width:600px;
margin:40px auto;
border-radius:$br;
box-shadow:0 4px 10px 4px rgba($form-bg,.3);
}

.tab-group {
list-style:none;
 padding:0;
 margin:0 0 40px 0;
 &:after {
 content: "";
 display: table;
 clear: both;
}
li a {
display:block;
text-decoration:none;
padding:15px;
background:rgba($gray-light,.25);
color:$gray-light;
font-size:20px;
float:left;
width:50%;
text-align:center;
cursor:pointer;
transition:.5s ease;
&:hover {
  background:$main-dark;
  color:$white;
}
}
.active a {
background:$main;
color:$white;
 }
}

.tab-content > div:last-child {
display:none;
}


 h1 {
 text-align:center;
  color:$white;
  font-weight:$thin;
  margin:0 0 40px;
  }

  label {
   position:absolute;
   transform:translateY(6px);
   left:13px;
    color:rgba($white,.5);
    transition:all 0.25s ease;
   -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  pointer-events: none;
 font-size:22px;
.req {
margin:2px;
color:$main;
}
}

label.active {
transform:translateY(50px);
left:2px;
font-size:14px;
.req {
opacity:0;
}
}

  label.highlight {
 color:$white;
 }

input, textarea {
font-size:22px;
display:block;
width:100%;
height:100%;
padding:5px 10px;
background:none;
background-image:none;
border:1px solid $gray-light;
color:$white;
border-radius:0;
transition:border-color .25s ease, box-shadow .25s ease;
&:focus {
    outline:0;
    border-color:$main;
}
}

 textarea {
   border:2px solid $gray-light;
  resize: vertical;
  }

 .field-wrap {
 position:relative;
 margin-bottom:40px;
} 

  .top-row {
  &:after {
  content: "";
   display: table;
  clear: both;
   }

> div {
float:left;
width:48%;
margin-right:4%;
&:last-child { 
  margin:0;
}
}
}

.button {
 border:0;
 outline:none;
 border-radius:0;
 padding:15px 0;
 font-size:2rem;
font-weight:$bold;
text-transform:uppercase;
letter-spacing:.1em;
background:$main;
color:$white;
transition:all.5s ease;
-webkit-appearance: none;
&:hover, &:focus {
background:$main-dark;
  }
 }

 .button-block {
display:block;
width:100%;
}

.forgot {
 margin-top:-20px;
text-align:right;
}
```

Comment: can you share a js fiddle

Comment: What are you trying to do here ?

Comment: "Not working" doesn't help us understand your problem

Comment: i want this code on text area field, when user type something then the text inside the text field should fadeout but its not working

Comment: I created a snippet and gave a better title. Now complete the snippet with the HTML and CSS to create a [mcve]

Comment: mplungjan .. sir i had html and css files .. both r workin but that code are not effecting the output

Comment: We do not know - please add! How can we test without complete test example

Answer (score 0):

Please use the syntax like this

```
$('form').find('input[type=text],textarea').on(...
```

Comment: @shaikhhasan - we do not know what "does not work" mean. Error messages in console? Please update your question with HTML and CSS and explain actual result versus expected result